# What is the wrong in this merge sort?

Tags: c, mergesort

```
#include <stdio.h>
int output[50];

void mergesort (int a[], int low, int high);
void merge ( int a[], int l, int m, int h );

int main(void)
{

    int n,a[50],i;
    printf("Enter total elements\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter the elements\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    mergesort(a,0,n-1);
    printf("The sorted elements are\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf("%d\n",output[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void mergesort (int a[], int low, int high)
{

    int mid;
    if ( low < high )
    {
        mid = (low+high)/2;
        mergesort(a,0,mid);
        mergesort(a,mid+1,high);
        merge(a,low,mid,high);
    }

}

void merge ( int a[], int l, int m, int h )
{
    int i = l,j = m+1;
    int temp[50],z,t=l;

    while ( (i <= m) && (j <= h) )
    {

        if (a[i] <= a[j])
        {
            temp[t] = a[i];
            t++;
            i++;
        }

        else
        {
            temp[t] = a[j];
            t++;
            j++;
        }

    }

    while ( i <= m )
    {
        temp[t] = a[i];
        i++;
        t++;
    }

    while ( j <= h )
    {
        temp[t] = a[j];
        j++;
        t++;
    }

    for ( z = l; z <= h; z++ )
    {
        output[z] = temp[z];
    }

}
```

I made this implementation of mergesort in C. However, it has some problem. 
The output comes out to be 321654 when I put the input as 123456. Seems I am missing out on some loop. When I input 54321, it shows the output as 21543. What is the problem, I am not able to understand. Please help.

Comment: Try to debug code by printing expected value/arguments etc at different part of your code

Comment: You can start by learning to indent your code. This is, for all intents and purposes, unreadable as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

last statement should be `a[z] = temp[z];` instead of `output[z] = temp[z];` and print `a` array. In merge sort previous merge results are used so if you copy to new array no proper merging is done.

Comment: but that is producing 0 output.

Comment: @user2848254 merging is done is main array itself so print `a` array and not `output` array

Comment: correct ..... my fault

Answer (score 0):

You've got one array too many: Delete `output` and write the contents of the temporary array `temp` directly back to `a`, so that each call of `merge` can see the changes the deeper recursions have made.

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest you change

```
mergesort(a,0,mid);
```

to

```
mergesort(a,low,mid);
```

Then replace

```
output[z] = temp[z];
```

with

```
a[z] = temp[z];
```